# Dynamic AQL query with ES6 literal template

Tags: templates, ecmascript-6, arangodb, aql

I would like to generate a query dynamically in Foxx. The filter statement would be there or not depend on the request parameter. For example

```
//Conditionally determine if we should include a filter statement here or not
var var1=true;
getAllEntitiesThatSatisfyTheCondition = db._query(aql `
      For u In ${EntityCollection}
      ${var1 ? `Filter u.prop == ${var1}`:``}
      Return DISTINCT u._id
    `).toArray();
```

This one would return an error about binding value

```
syntax error, unexpected bind parameter
```

How can I construct the query using literal template this way in arango, or I have to use query builder?

Comment: There are some (not yet unreleased) changes to the ArangoJS driver that should help you, namely the handling of `undefined` (will be omitted instead of generating a bind variable with no value) and nesting support: https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Related: [AQL template in arango Foxx does not work correctly with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967790/aql-template-in-arango-foxx-does-not-work-correctly-with-array/) (ArangoJS v6.7.0 supports nesting of templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Foxx using Arango 3.3.16:

```
var test = "1124852" 
const filter = aql.literal(
    test ? `AND v._key == "${test}" ` : ''
  );
```

then on your query just add

```
${filter}
```

Comment: Goes without saying that literals do not validate the parameters, so use with caution and validate properly to avoid injection

Comment: When I use your suggestion into the exact query I have above, there is a new problem as "AQL: syntax error, unexpected assignment near..."

Comment: Nevermind, it was the error of using !==. I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below as well.

```
var filter = "FILTER a.name=='test'";


var query = `
   for a IN collection1
  "${filter}"
 limit 50
  return a
`;

db._query(query).toArray();
```

Here the javascript filter variable will be replaced dynamically. Hope this helps.